# i want to send a message to whatsapp from twilio API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, twilio

Hi i'm using twilio API to send a message to whatsapp number what i need is to get the number and message from a form and put the data in the twilio API i don't now how to build the logic but i did this but didn't work and i got this error

```
(node:13568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at sendMessage (/home/azoozalharte/سطح المكتب/s3ad7/controllers/index.js:12:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13568) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
POST /s3ad7 - - ms - -
```

so this is my controllers file that i wrote the logic init

```
const S3aad7 = require('../models/s3ad7'); 
const accountSid = 'AC6e367ad8e26d8686c419f0f2e6e250e9';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid ,process.env.AUTH_TOKEN);


module.exports =  {
   async sendMessage(req, res, next){
       let msg = await S3aad7.create(req.body.msg);
       client.messages
       .create({
          from: 'whatsapp:+18456179969',
          body: msg.body,
          to: `whatsapp:+${msg.receivedNumber}`
        })
       .then(message => console.log(message.sid));

    }
}
```

and this is my view file that i need to get the data form it

```
<form action="/s3ad7" method="POST">

    <input type="text" name="msg[receivedNumber]" placeholder="الرقم مع رمز الدوله" id="">
    <input type="text" name="msg[body]" placeholder="رسالتك" id="">
    <input type="submit" name="" id="">

</form>
```

and this is my models file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const s3ad7Schema = Schema({
    receivedNumber: String,
    body: String
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('S3ad7', s3ad7Schema);
```

and this is the real code from twilio docs

```
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
// DANGER! This is insecure. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = 'AC6e367ad8e26d8686c419f0f2e6e250e9';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({
         from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
         body: 'Hello there!',
         to: 'whatsapp:+15005550006'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

i hope i explained what i need exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try "${msg.body}" instead of "msg.body", like this:

```
module.exports =  {
   async sendMessage(req, res, next){
       let msg = await S3aad7.create(req.body.msg);
       client.messages
       .create({
          from: 'whatsapp:+18456179969',
          body: ${msg.body},
          to: `whatsapp:+${msg.receivedNumber}`
        })
       .then(message => console.log(message.sid));

    }
}
```